# Guessing game - Too high. Too low

Tags: python, algorithm, number-guessing-game

I will post 2 scripts that are doing (supposedly) the same thing. First one is the script i created, second one is the solution from the course.

What would you consider wrong (if anything) with the script that i made? Should i think scripts more like the second one, with functions and so?

**My script**

```
import random

print(art.logo)
print("Welcome to the number guessing game! ")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")

difficulty = input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ")

ATTEASY = 10
ATTHARD = 5
playAgain = True

while playAgain :
  numberIs = random.randint(0,100)
  atteasy = ATTEASY
  atthard = ATTHARD
  
  while atteasy and atthard != 0 :  
    if difficulty == "easy" :
      print(f"You have {atteasy} attempts remaining to guess the number. ")
      guess = input("Make a guess: ")
      if int(guess) == numberIs : 
        print(f"You are right! The number was indeed {numberIs}")
        break
      else : 
        if int(guess) > numberIs :
          print("To high.")
        else : 
          print("To low.")
        atteasy = atteasy - 1
        if atteasy != 0 : 
          print("Guess again.")
    else :
      print(f"You have {atthard} attempts remaining to guess the number. ")
      guess = input("Make a guess: ")
      if int(guess) == numberIs : 
        print(f"You are right! The number was indeed {numberIs}")
        break
      else : 
        if int(guess) > numberIs :
          print("To high.")
        else : 
          print("To low.")  
        atthard = atthard - 1
        if atthard != 0 : 
          print("Guess again.")
        
  if atteasy or atthard == 0 :
    print(f"You lost. The numbers was {numberIs}")
  break
```

**Script from the course**

For comparison, not for review:

> ```
> from random import randint
>
> EASY_LEVEL_TURNS = 10
> HARD_LEVEL_TURNS = 5
>
> #Function to check user's guess against actual answer.
> def check_answer(guess, answer, turns):
>   """checks answer against guess. Returns the number of turns remaining."""
>   if guess > answer:
>     print("Too high.")
>     return turns - 1
>   elif guess < answer:
>     print("Too low.")
>     return turns - 1
>   else:
>     print(f"You got it! The answer was {answer}.")
>
> #Make function to set difficulty.
> def set_difficulty():
>   level = input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ")
>   if level == "easy":
>     return EASY_LEVEL_TURNS
>   else:
>     return HARD_LEVEL_TURNS
>
> def game():
>   #Choosing a random number between 1 and 100.
>   print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
>   print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
>   answer = randint(1, 100)
>   print(f"Pssst, the correct answer is {answer}") 
>
>   turns = set_difficulty()
>   #Repeat the guessing functionality if they get it wrong.
>   guess = 0
>   while guess != answer:
>     print(f"You have {turns} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
>
>     #Let the user guess a number.
>     guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
>
>     #Track the number of turns and reduce by 1 if they get it wrong.
>     turns = check_answer(guess, answer, turns)
>     if turns == 0:
>       print("You've run out of guesses, you lose.")
>       return
>     elif guess != answer:
>       print("Guess again.")
>
> game()
> ```

Answer (score 7):

### Your script

First of all, it won't run since `art` is undefined. I'm going to assume that this is some kind of ASCII art you didn't include in the question.

Avoid putting all of your code right into the global namespace; use functions instead.

`playAgain` should be named `play_again`.

Your logic dividing up `atteasy` and `atthard` has a lot of repeated code. Why not just make one `attempt` variable that's conditionally assigned before your loop?

Grammar: `to high` and `to low` should be `too high` and `too low`.

Your `int(guess)` assumes that the user entered an integer which may not be the case; this would benefit from validation.

You should indent at four spaces and not two.

### What should be done instead

- indent at four spaces instead of two
- add functions, and add type hints to the signature of those functions
- write subroutines such as a `check_answer` that compares the answer and guess, and returns a boolean indicating whether the guess was successful
- All `#comments` that you add should have a space between the hash and the text.
- Add `"""docstrings"""` to the first line inside your functions. No other comments before the functions are necessary.
- Consider writing a subroutine to set the number of guesses based on a difficulty lookup dictionary
- Your entry point should be wrapped in a `__main__` guard

### Suggested

Based roughly on the "course" script.

```
from random import randint

DIFFICULTIES = {
    'easy': 10,
    'hard': 5,
}


def check_answer(guess: int, answer: int) -> bool:
    """checks answer against guess. Returns true if the guess was correct."""

    if guess == answer:
        print(f"You got it! The answer was {answer}.")
        return True

    if guess > answer:
        direction = "high"
    else:
        direction = "low"

    print(f"Too {direction}.")
    return False


def set_difficulty() -> int:
    names = ', '.join(DIFFICULTIES.keys())
    while True:
        level = input(f"Choose a difficulty. Type one of: {names}: ")
        difficulty = DIFFICULTIES.get(level)
        if difficulty is not None:
            return difficulty


def game() -> None:
    print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
    print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
    answer = randint(1, 100)
    print(f"Pssst, the correct answer is {answer}")

    turns = set_difficulty()

    for turn in range(turns, 0, -1):
        print(f"You have {turn} attempts remaining to guess the number.")

        while True:
            try:
                guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid number.")

        if check_answer(guess, answer):
            return

    print("You've run out of guesses, you lose.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game()
```

Comment: This review has useful content and I upvoted it. But it lacks a definitive statement that the scripts' problems are not equivalently serious. So I guess I'll make that statement here: put your code in functions, folks.

Comment: Woa. This is amazing. Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much !

Comment: @FMc Thank you for your answer. But can you explain why? Why shoul i put my code into functions?

Comment: The site rules forbid reviewing third-party code. Could you either rephrase the critique of the course's code as advice for the poster, or delete that part of your answer?

Comment: @perj It's a big topic and there are many reasons. You could read some of my reviews on this site and I'm sure you'll find a variety of such reasons. Or you could search the internet with your query and find many explanations. It's a worthy topic to learn about if you're trying to become more skilled.

Comment: @200_success Sure; I've modified my language

Answer (score 1):

I think here are two examples where you either do not fully understand Python syntax or should maybe make it more explicit what you mean:

```
while atteasy and atthard != 0 :
```

and

```
if atteasy or atthard == 0 :
```

Python parses the latter as:

```
if (atteasy) or (atthard == 0):
```

and not as

```
if (atteasy == 0) or (atthard == 0):
```

In Python non-zero integers are truthy and zero is falsey, so `if atteasy` and `if atteasy != 0` are the same, as long as the variable is an integer. See these examples:

```
a, b = 1, 4
if a and b == 4:
    print("This will print")

c, d = 0, 4
if c or d == 0:
    print("This will not print")
```

Either you wanted it to be this way, then you should probably make it explicit:

```
if atteasy != 0 or atthard == 0:
```

Or you did not mean it and you should fix it with one of these (in this case) equivalent ways:

```
if atteasy == 0 or atthard == 0:
if not atteasy or not atthard:
if not (atteasy and atthard):
if 0 in (atteasy, atthard):
```